# Are multiple answers by the same user acceptable?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

I came across this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570596/secure-login-register-system-with-email-validation

and a fairly experienced user (2 years+ on SO) has posted an answer that is three scripts and instead of including them in one answer has posted three separate answers.
I've commented that they would be better and less confusing if they were all put into one answer but thought I'd best check here first.

I've looked at [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) .

Which kind of answers the question, but from a more experienced user's point of view I'd like to know what they would do in this particular circumstance?

Comment: The question itself is far to broad to start with.

Comment: Question is too broad and 3 answers are, well, not answers at all. They are all copy-pasted content and without any comment line, it is nearly impossible to understand what most lines are doing. A total mess IMO.

Comment: @rene, looks like 4 people have downvoted all the answers - last time I downvoted 3 answers from a user they were serial reversed :(

Comment: @RichardTingle I actually mention that link in my question, I wanted a viewpoint on this specific case though. However the title has been changed to be so generic now and can understand you raising it as a duplicate.

Comment: My personal preference is for a specific answer + closed as duplicate as the best of both worlds. But if you object strongly I can retract my vote

Comment: In a more general sense, [there are some good examples of where this would be (arguably) appropriate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/javascript-random-seeds).

Comment: To answer the question title: Yes, multiple complete answers of the same person are as acceptable as if they came from different persons. Indeed, the fact that it's the same or different persons is completely irrelevant. The body of the question deals more with incomplete answers.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That's definitely not appropriate.  The *only* situation where posting multiple answers to the same question may be appropriate is when each of the answers, on its own, could be a valid and complete answer to the question.

In this case, it appears that the answerer simply split his long answer into three parts.  The second and third parts should be edited into the first one, and then flagged for deletion.

**Edit:** It looks like the reason they did that is because the combined answer would exceed the 30,000 character length limit.  IMO, that's still not, in itself, a sufficient reason to split an answer — it simply indicates that the answer you're trying to post is way too long for SO.  It does, however, somewhat complicate dealing with this particular situation, except perhaps by simply deleting it all.

(On a closer look, the answer(s) is full of pretty awful copy-paste spaghetti code, anyway, and the question itself is indeed way too broad.  I'd recommend closing and deleting the whole mess.)

Comment: I didn't feel right commenting on the code, but assumed maybe it's something they have used themselves and in an effort to be helpful posted their entire solution. Personally don't find that useful especially if the OP isn't experienced.

Comment: Exceeding 30k chars is a good reason. Else, how could you describe [how SSL works](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work)?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, if exceeding 30k characters is a good reason to split an answer, why is there a limit? Clearly a limit tells you that answers should not exceed 30k characters. Fully agree with Ilmari that "it simply indicates that the answer you're trying to post is way too long for SO"

Comment: @CodesInChaos I imagine you can explain how SSL works by pasting in an xkcd explanation... but I cannot prove that with an example :)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Ever seen this close reason: "**too broad**
There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Comment: @BenVoigt It's not quite cut and dried that splitting the answer due to length is bad. It just needs exceptional reasons, which didn't exist here.

Comment: How can I flag for deletion? "not an answer"? I already got it declined on [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30524448/1276636), even though I added a comment under the flagged answer, as can be seen.

Comment: @Sufian A custom mod flag would be appropriate in this case (and more generally in cases where something should be deleted but none of the canned reasons fit).

Comment: "each of the answers, on its own, could be a valid and complete answer to the question." this allows for me to copy paste the same answer several times. There needs to be some concept of distinctness among the answers

Comment: @JoelBerkeley: Hence the "may be". Each answer being valid on its own is a necessary condition for appropriateness, but not sufficient on its own. I'm sure  with some thought one could come up with plenty of other creative ways in which posting multiple answers to the same question _could_ be inappropriate, even if each answer alone would be acceptable.

Comment: do you fancy making that more clear that in your answer (necessary but not sufficient)? It's not how I read your answer