# "Add Another Answer" button - Why is that option available?

Tags: discussion, answers, multiple-answers

I don't know how this option escaped my eyes all these years, but after having posted an answer recently I suddenly saw the "Add Another Answer" button right at the bottom of the page.

If it's there, then it must be for a reason. Just curious about what conditions would entitle adding two answers from the same user for the same question.

Comment: I guess it might also be on-topic on MSE, oh! it is [already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) there.

Comment: It's quite helpful in SQL land. I've had answers in 2 different languages before... They come with different advice etc. so, it's a lot cleaner to separate them.

Comment: To discourage you from adding another answer.  You can if you really want to, clicking the button gives you another post box.

Comment: Basically, it's to discourage folks from adding to their answer with another answer, vs editing the original.  But the option is allowed (with a warning) since it's not uncommon for the answerer to have another, totally unrelated (except to the question) answer, and it's better to keep distinct answers separate.  I think it strikes the right balance (something that's unusual enough on SO to merit extra appreciation).

Comment: Elsemeta, I wrote [Why was my question closed or down voted?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6483/) which has one answer for each reason.  With the lack of linkable headers, this provides a way to link to each section/answer independently and directly.

Comment: An own tag just for this question? Why?

Comment: @Manu uh? What do you mean? Nevermind..I think you're referring to multiple-answers

Comment: I answered twice before. The first was a technically correct way I solved the question myself. After several comments, including the OP originally disliking my answer looking for a more 'finesse' answer, I provided another based on some research and testing I did based on some of those comments. My original answer was eventually accepted, but that second approach provided a very interesting path to solving OP's question. Here is the link if you interested in that example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397780/scrollviewer-indication-of-child-element-scrolled-into-view/19398661#19398661

Comment: A recent example of mine, where I suggested two different approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23762322/3001761

Comment: Is there a contest going on between which vote wins xD ?

Comment: related: [Are multiple answers by the same user acceptable?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251070/839601)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Quite simply because you could have two different answers to the same problem. Rather than editing your original answer into a long monstrosity you can instead add another.

It's seldom used though. It is done in this way to make it obvious that you've already tendered an answer, it cuts down on people who used to just add another answer instead of editing (and adding to) their previous one.

As for it being unnecessary: well, maybe. Just because it is seldom used it doesn't mean that we should outright prevent people from adding another answer should they want to.

Comment: Well, in that case wouldn't it mean that the question is too broad?

Comment: @asprin: not necessarily. A lot of programming questions can be answered in different ways while still being very specific.

Comment: Be that as it may, I find the notion of adding another answer quite unnecessary. Though you have pointed out that it is used very rarely, I feel that the justification for the presence of that button would warrant more reasons

Comment: It is rare but it does happen to have two valid and different solutions to a problem - each should be in a separate answer. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17901588/761202) where I gave two different answers to the same question; they are two different routes to achieve the same goal - The accepted answer was actually born out of discussion of the earlier answer, editing an already complete answer to say "or you could do this" didn't seem appropriate, and would just distract. In my years I've done that exactly once.

Answer (score 9):

Some questions have more than one good answer, and some users might want to provide multiple approaches.

Readers then get an opportunity to pick their favorite one. There's no need for the answerer to judge which is best, and no need for a run-on answer where it's too easy to miss solutions after the first.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3918968/153285) an example of a question I multiply answered. I seem to recall one where I even posted three.

Comment: I recall someone posting two separate answers, the answers being total opposites of each other. I don't recall on what site and what question, but I found it quite interesting.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I also recall someone coming back a month or two later, who posted a new answer disagreeing with himself.  (I think it was a unit/integration test question, and some recent experience completely changed his views)