# Could deleting my answer improve OP's chances of getting a better answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I feel (and this may be a wrong assumption) that an upvoted question without answers would attract more StackOverflow users than a question with an upvoted (but not accepted) answer, as people may think that the answer is correct but OP just didn't accept it, preventing better/more complete solutions.

For example, my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767342/javascript-focusoffset-with-html-tags) works in many cases, but it doesn't work for OP's case (added later as a comment). As it is a possible (although incomplete) answer, I think I should not delete it because it could help other users that visit the question, but at the same time I believe that keeping it could undermine OP's chances of getting a better answer during the first few hours the question was asked (when it's listed in a more prominent space on the site).

I'd say the best option (and what I'll probably do) for a case like this would be to start a bounty, but the question is still not old enough for that. And even then, by the time the bounty is posted and gets a better answer, it may be useful for future users but "too late" for OP. How to proceed meanwhile? Just let it be?

Comment: I think the straightforward answer to *"Could deleting my answer improve OP's chances of getting a better answer?"* is *don't know*. Maybe some SEDE wizard could write a query that will tell you whether unanswered questions get answered more quickly than second answers appearing on answered-but-unaccepted questions *on average*, but that's beyond my SQiLs and doesn't address your specific case.

Comment: _people may think that the answer is correct but OP just didn't accept it_ - It doesn't seem likely that many people would be so certain of this that they wouldn't even click on the question to check. People might think it's likely that the existing answer is correct but they'd probably still look to be sure.

Comment: There's no guarantee that your removed answer _will_ result in a better answer. Just leave it, a partial answer is better than no answer IMO. Good question btw.

Comment: A question not getting any new answers may have more to do with the age than with existing answers. But hey, perhaps you're onto something.

Comment: Maybe you could add _EDIT: Doesn't work for the OP_ in bold letters at the top of your answer so people who don't read the comments still answer.

Comment: @jakekimds shouldn't an answer be removed if it doesn't work? If it doesn't work for the OP specifically, well, that usually indicates the problem is something different.

Comment: If you do decide to delete your answer, consider asking and self-answering another question to preserve the information in the answer for other readers (and edit the first question to explain how it's different).

Comment: I didn't delete the answer. I initially added an edit as suggested by @jakeimds. Then later found a different solution that fit better OP's requirements and added it as a second edit.

Comment: We have a Late Answers queue for answers from people who are compelled to answer questions which may have already been answered. I don't really see this as a big issue. Also, as you say, your answer may very well be of help to others who have similar, if not exactly the same, questions.

Comment: @Matt I just meant to keep the answer for future reference if someone has a similar problem.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro rather than the big block of **Edit**, I would suggest adding it as a separate answer

Comment: @jonrsharpe I debated about that for a while because it is a completely different solution, and checking on meta I didn't find a clear answer. I will copy it as a separate response, although both of my solutions have some time of flaw :(

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro see e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255360/3001761 - the functionality wouldn't exist if it wasn't OK (in some circumstances). *"both of my solutions have some time of flaw"* - that's not necessarily a problem as long as you mention what it is! Perfect is the enemy of good, after all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. I updated the old answer, and separated them into two

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Pretty doubtful.  I can't speak for everyone, but seeing a question with answers never slowed me down having a look at it.  Rather the opposite, I might learn something from the existing answers.

When you get an "Oh, forgot to mention a nasty not-so-little detail" comment then you're off the hook having to deal with that in my book.  If the OP edits his question and adds it, thus invalidating your answer, then it is up to you to decide how to deal with that.  Including and not limited to rolling back the edit.  Don't get in a edit war over it however.

Don't delete your answer.  Another programmer might find it back some day and not have the same nasty little detail.

Comment: When looking for questions to answer, I usually skip questions which already have one, without looking. I only have so much time, and I'd rather focus on unanswered questions (by tag) except if the title wakes my interest. Even so, I agree that OP should not delete his answer.

Comment: I won't delete my answer. But I feel I may be "stealing answerers" from the question as I do something similar to what @Jester mentions

Comment: Well, it is my opinion that you don't.  Looks like a popular opinion.  Fwiw, the OP hasn't bothered to update his question so it is rather essential that other users can read about the nasty little detail from your post.  The odds he'll get a better answer are rather slim, he's just not doing it right.  That is not your problem either.

Comment: Mostly great answer, but advising people to roll back edits that askers make to their *own* questions just because it invalidates *their* answer doesn't seem like the best idea. Not that that would *never* be a good idea, that's just the kind of advice that's bound to be misapplied.

Comment: @Jester, I agree, when looking to answer general questions.  But when researching questions *I* have, I often review with scrutiny, to make sure other visitors have a good experience.

Comment: I always love to answer very first.

Answer (score 15):

From the perspective of someone looking for answers to questions (rather than questions to answer) I find that in more than half of all cases the unaccepted answers provide the clues I need to solve the problem that got me to the page in the first place. Searching for clues to fixing problems will often lead to questions that don't exactly match the problem, so answers that don't exactly match the original question can be the answer to the question I would have asked.

In short, any answer may help solve a problem, even if it's not the solution to the original question; don't delete.

Comment: Great perspective. I can't agree more.

Comment: Indeed! Especially when the question has nasty little details, it's often the case that the accepted answer isn't the best one, and even if another answer scores higher than the accepted one it might not be the perfect solution either. Sadly, when an answer is highly technical it may not get the upvotes it deserves, since competing answers that are easier to understand may attract the votes even if they ignore some nasty little details. So when I search old questions to solve a problem I generally read all the answers to try & distill all the information I can get out of them.