# What flag should I use for multiple answers if any?

Tags: discussion, flags, multiple-answers

I came across an question which the same user had answered twice. The second answer was a clarification of the first answer and could easily have been an edit instead. I checked on the [etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) and found that this is [generally frowned upon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251070/are-multiple-answers-by-the-same-user-acceptable), but could not find what the procedure is to address such double answers.

The "not an answer" flag is not appropriate because both posts are valid although incomplete answers. Another option would be to raise a custom flag, but I know these require moderator attention, so I wanted to check that this is the correct approach first.

I left a comment for the author, and the author deleted the second answer, so this question is just for future reference/curiousity.

Comment: I you don't get any response from the OP after you've left your comment, then yes... a "other" flag would be most appropriate. The alternative would be to flag as "NAA" or "VLQ" and hope the users in the VLQ queue would piece together the flag and the comment you've left, and work out what happened... I'm not too hopeful of that though.

Comment: Harm for come from the content being deleted, therefore I think a comment with no other action is best, as at worce the reader has to read both answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've fixed a few of these in the past, and the way I do it is to edit the secondary answer back into the primary answer, then use an *Other* flag on the secondary message to explain what I've done and to ask the mod to delete that secondary message.

My approach is to try and remove the message that will cause less harm (i.e. loss of rep) to the author - you're trying to help them, not punish them.

**However...** in your case you have insufficient rep to achieve this by yourself, and you don't want to take your chances with a suggested edit. Nor do you necessarily want to bug a moderator to make the edits - that's not their job. In this case you got lucky and the answer belonged to an active user who took action straight away. If leaving a comment is not worthwhile (i.e. it's an answer from an inactive or infrequent user) then you should do what you've done - post on Meta, but make sure you include links to the appropriate answers so that a more privileged user can do the edits for you.