# Why multiple answers to a question are allowed by the same user who already have answered?Why not editing the original answer

Tags: discussion, answers, multiple-answers

Yesterday I commented on the answer of a user near to the 10k at Stack Overflow who have posted multiple answers to a question.

> Excuse me,Considering your reputation I should not be telling this to
>   you, but please avoid giving multiple answers on the same
>   question..Thank you.. :)

and in response he nicely replied

> There's nothing wrong with having two answers to a question. The
>   system allows for it. I've combined them anyway.

[Link to the Answer below which we had a small discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26818997/681929)

I don't know why, but I am having a feeling even if the system allows, I must not be posting multiple answers to a question (I don't know why I am having it). But why system is allowing multiple answer to the same question by a user who have already answered for the question? (Although the OP can select only one, but can upvote all the other answers)

**Soon this will be marked as duplicate of**: [Are multiple answers by the same user acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251070/are-multiple-answers-by-the-same-user-acceptable) 
but why multiple answers are even allowed? If I have given some answer on a question then I must not be able to submit another answer to the same question (I must edit the answer, if I want to add something)

Comment: Because you could have two *completely* different approaches to the problem, and you want them to be judged on their own merits (I've done this once before). Its *rare* that you want to do this, but it does happen.

Comment: Note: I don't think the user in this case should have answered twice. It **is** ok in some cases though.

Comment: Two similar answers are inappropriate. Two completely different approaches are fine, and are even better posted as two answers.

Comment: Why not clubbing both the approaches in a single answer, both having visually distinguishable headings **1.Approach 1 .... 2.Approach 2**  @BradleyDotNET

Comment: I can think of three reasons: (1) As a voter, maybe I like one approach but think the other is just "meh". Do I upvote? Downvote? if the posts are separate, I can upvote one, and ignore/downvote the other. (2) Similarly, as a user, I can see upvotes for the one approach. If they were combined, I don't know which is better! (3) If both approaches are valid (and good answers) the poster deserves the "double rep" for providing two valid solutions.

Comment: Consider a scenario, You explained soemthing by Approach 1, and there are 10 other answers too,You explained best,but then you suddenly find out  that i can tell the OP about second approach too,Now you will answer second time....But,I don't think your second answer will rise up foR the OP,on the other hand if you edit your answer(which is becoming famous with in seconds) and add a comment "please see the edit" will be better

Comment: Everything around this will always be case-by-case. I will commonly present multiple approaches in a single answer. I've also posted multiple answers once. However, if you can actually create a completely different answer; then there is no reason you shouldn't be allowed to post it as one. I don't have a problem with people that edit extra approaches into their answers (as long as it doesn't get *ridiculously* long). I also don't have a problem with those that post 2 complete answers separately. It all depends on what the poster wanted to do/felt was right.

Answer (score 1):

In programming, there are multiple solutions to a problem. There isn't one best way to solve it. You could use different design patterns, different algorithms, or different methods to come to a solution.

As far as I'm concerned, there is no rule requiring you to only have one answer to a question. I would even encourage it, as it adds knowledge to the community.

You never know how long it will take for someone else to come up with the same solution. So, getting it early is more than welcome.