# Should I separate my answer in few posts?

Tags: discussion, answers

Today I came across а question with 3 different answers by the same author: [Stack size under Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817790/stack-size-under-mono)

Is this a good practice or I should add all my different options/answers into a single post?

Comment: Relevant, possible duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251070/1558022 I think this particular example falls under “each of the answers, on its own, could be a valid and complete answer to the question”.

Comment: With three very different approaches, separate answers also allows the asker and the community to indicate through voting/accepting which is the preferred option.

Comment: This is actually an interesting approach. If I find there may be more than a single answer, I weigh "best answers the question" against "best answer, period", and only touch upon the other(s). But that doesn't actually tell me what the OP decided to use!

Comment: It is a fairly silly thing to do.  The question had a bounty so perhaps the poster tried to prevent anybody else from posting a "better" answer by covering all possibilities.  Not that it worked, the OP never actually picked any of them.  Too much choice :)