# Why there is an option to answer the same question more than once by same person?

Tags: discussion, answers

Why is a person allowed to give more than one answer to a same question?

Does it look better to have different answer from the same person? Why not give the alternative solution in the first answer post?

Comment: *Why not he/she give the alternative solution in giving the answer first time itself* Because then you cannot vote on each approach separately.

Comment: Related: [Are multiple answers by the same user acceptable?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251070)

Comment: Also see [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209)

Comment: Some of us have multiple personalities.

Comment: My only (that I remember) double answers were written in 2 different languages...

Comment: @Deduplicator: related, not a dupe in my opinion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think calling that not a dupe is splitting the hairs a bit too fine.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The other post is almost entirely about a specific off-topic question where the answer posted is way, way too long. It only briefly mentions why one normally would use multiple answers. It doesn't invite discussion on the uses of the feature; e.g. if someone disagrees with my answer posted below they cannot post a dissenting view on that other question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Shouldn't dupe-closing the other way around be appropriate then?

Comment: @Deduplicator: perhaps, now that that specific case is handled. Not sure though.

Comment: ok..fine...But I don't think its duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, and probably *should* post multiple answers if the problem can be solved in different, very distinct ways. Some programming languages naturally offer different approaches to solving the same problem for example.

By posting separate answers the community can vote on each approach *separately*. If you put the two approaches into one answer, and one approach is terrible and the other is great, how should the community vote on that one answer?

Comment: Thanks for your precious answer..I shall keep it in mind..while answering to questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not?

Giving 2 different solutions in different answers can be more readable and the community can vote on the better one instead on the general answer.

And on sites like meta you can have multiple answers for bug reports for instance.