# One Question Multiple answers from a user

Tags: discussion, comments, duplicate-answers

Referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205067/how-to-delete-if-the-data-is-duplicate) question.

A user already answered and his answer is accepted.

But the questionnaire raised some doubts through comments.

Instead of updating the answer for the doubts, he gave a new answer.

I referred this question in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251070/are-multiple-answers-by-the-same-user-acceptable). But it didn't give a clear picture about what we should do in this stackoverflow question?.

I raised a moderator attention to the answer and explained the scenario. It is still pending.

Is the answers seems to be duplicate?. Do I need to flag the answers?

Comment: The OP should have edited their original answer, instead of giving two new ones. You may downvote the additional answers an leave a comment, that these should be merged to the 1st answer.

Comment: Please explain why this question downvoted?

Comment: I have no clue, voting on Meta is different.