# How much must 2 answers by the same user differ?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I flagged a month ago [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34177783/3850595) because is [almost the same](https://www.diffchecker.com/WI4oYRCN) as the [accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34178268/3850595). I used (and upvoted) accepted one, but downvoted and flagged the second one (almost duplicate).

The flag is still awaiting for resolution (+30 days), which makes me ask a side question: *how long can flags wait until solved?*.

But point is... both answers are long but quite similar because important part ([see in diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/WI4oYRCN)) are just 10 different lines.

As long as SO warns you when you try to add 2 answers in same question:

> Are you sure you want to add another answer?
>
> You could use the edit link to improve or refine your existing answer, instead.

- Should both answers be merged?
- Are them different enough to justify a double answer from same user?

Comment: I had a mod flag take a month and a half to process 2 month back.

Comment: @nathan, flag solving time is just a side question, maybe my thoughts (and flag) are wrong.... That's why I'm asking how much must answers differ

Comment: Looks like the same user posted 2 different answers as there is two different ways to do this.  Not seeing anything wrong here.

Comment: should not be same answer with 2 options better? is there a rule?

Comment: Its really up to the user I tihnk.  If there is not much difference I tend to post both options in the same answer.  Not sure what the line is here.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251070/are-multiple-answers-by-the-same-user-acceptable

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Comment: Two answers must differ in their essence.

Answer (score 8):

In this case, the full code needs to be included in the post in order to make the Stack Snippet work. That's certainly a reason to write the full code in *both* answers, not just the important part(s). I don't see anything wrong in having two answers on this question, especially since the important parts are definitely different. The rest is just 'fluff', but necessary to make the snippets work.

They probably *could* make this work in a single snippet, but that would require additional explanation in the form of 'the blue marker is done with option 1, and the purple marker with option 2'. IMHO, that would be more confusing.

Comment: *The rest is just 'fluff'* that's the point, if you see two methods full of same lines you will think this is not correct, one answer with both options (and all *fluff*) will be clearer. Also, posting two long answers  seems redundant...

Comment: @JordiCastilla If you feel that one or both answers end up being not helpful as a result of that, you're certainly welcome to use your votes to reflect that, but I don't see that as an argument for forcibly removing one of the answers.