# When should I give a second answer on the same question?

Tags: discussion, answers

There is a trend that when someone comes up with another approach to the same question they extend their answer despite the fact that it sometimes drastically changes the answer. When should I give a second answer to the same question and when I should edit the first answer with the new idea?

Comment: There is almost never a reason to add a second answer. About the only case I can think of is if you exceed the 30k character limit. Then you might need to break your answer up into two pieces (and possibly re-examine your life).

Comment: @CodyGray So you're saying it's a bad practice to add a other answer and one should prefer editing an existing one?

Comment: Yes. That's why the edit link exists, so you can improve your existing answer.

Comment: @CodyGray thank you! I'll try to comply with the guidance

Comment: I would disagree with Cody: When your second answer is, by itself, a complete and viable answer to the question, I feel it should be posted as a separate answer. If you put two answers into one, which answer are users voting on? Breaking an answer up because of the length seems like the wrong way to handle things- Like questions, each answer should be self-contained and not have to rely on other sources, including other answers on the same page. But two different approaches, two different answers, should be different answers.

Comment: Related: [Are multiple answers by the same user acceptable?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251070/are-multiple-answers-by-the-same-user-acceptable)

Comment: @Kendra I thought so too, but seen it many times here on stackoverflow that people try to nest two or even more independent answers in a single one. Other people don't argue with that so maybe it's preferred answers design... This is how my question emerged :)

Comment: There was another answer to the same question (which I couldn't find quickly) - add second answer when it suggests somewhat opposite approach to allow community to vote which one is better...

Comment: @Kendra while one-approach-per-answer could work in theory, it also means most people will not ever even know there are equally good alternative approaches as they don't look past first answer... I think splitting answers is useful when you know both solutions have issues and want community to decide on one (basically whichever get downvoted less :))

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov so if you cannot decide which version is better you listen to vox populi. Sounds reasonable.

Comment: What Kendra is suggesting is what people commonly do on Meta sites, where popularity is a relevant metric, and there is lots of room for healthy disagreement. This is *far* less common in programming problems. There is almost always one right answer, and you don't need a popularity contest to sort out which is best. I often include several alternatives in my answers, but I wouldn't want to post them as independent answers. It is, of course, up to you which one you decide to do.