# How to handle a user that leaves multiple answers per question?

Tags: discussion, flags, multiple-answers

I came across a user recently who I've noticed has added multiple answers to a single question in the past on SO. I don't believe adding multiple answers is necessarily a bad thing as long as they are relevant to the question and exist as independent answers that can stand on their own. This user in particular seems to add answers to [provide updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762887/how-to-hide-zero-values-in-a-chart-with-amchart-js/55763585#55763585) rather than editing

This user isn't heavily active but I did flag a recent occurrence of this with the mod flag. One of their answers to a recent question got deleted but their history remains. Did I do the right thing of mod flagging? Should I have also individually flagged each answer I saw in their answer history that seems to be noise? It felt wrong to go through an entire user's history to flag through so I only set the one flag. Or is their behavior not actually that looked down upon?

According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251070/are-multiple-answers-by-the-same-user-acceptable) meta post and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) I'm led to believe that I'm pretty sure its bad behavior on SO, but they are pretty old posts. Do I go through their entire history and flag or just set the one mod flag?

Comment: I think a mod flag is the way to go; they're the only ones who could delete the extra answer posts directly and they would need to send a message to the user encouraging them to edit their existing answers. Rather than flagging all of their answer history, explain in the custom message that they've done this on multiple questions.

Comment: Did you try pinging the poster asking why they add new answers rather than edit their existing ones?

Comment: Odds are the user was used to older forum environments where you can't edit previous posts (answers in our case), and each new post just appears in order after the previous one.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I did tag them in a comment but the comment (and their reply) has since been deleted so I didn't have time to see their response.

Comment: Yeah mods love to remove comments as quickly as possible before anybody even has a chance to read them. This ^ is a good example of why that needs to stop.

Comment: If you go to the user profile page, you will see he is actually a member for over 5 years. :O. Surely he must know the edit feature by now.

Comment: This question is likely about my answers.  I will refrain from creating multiple answers in the future.

Comment: @jeffld, We appreciate the work. Multiple answer can be a good thing. When the answers are different. While this question was about you it's not direct toward you many user may forgot that the edit button exist like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977301.

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892822. perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360273/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233451, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609310. Let those here if someone want to check if the answer are independant

Comment: @WizardofCoding Im pretty sure I linked that in the original question... my question isn't only about if its acceptable or not but what the correct action a regular user can take to address the problem.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Leaving multiple disjointed answers is indeed not a good idea. It just creates a mess. There's really no point in doing that.

As you say, multiple *independent* answers are okay if they really have so little overlap that it makes more sense to post them separately – but this isn't the case here.

Why that person did that, one can only speculate, but perhaps they just don't know about the "edit" functionality.

A single custom flag seems to be the appropriate action here. Including an explanation that this behaviour is a pattern, is helpful.

A comment to the author would also be a good way to inform them that using the edit link is what they should be doing, rather than posting multiple updates as different answers.

Comment: "multiple independent answers can be okay" Multiple independent answers should always be okay. It doesn't matter if they come from the same author or different authors.

Comment: Sounds like you and Jean-Francois are saying the same thing in different ways @Trilarion

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler Yes. Just wanted to make the statement as clear as possible. Formally there is a difference between can be and is with the latter being stronger.

Comment: @Trilarion: it's always technically ok but not always the *best* choice.  Sometimes it's better to add another section to an existing answer, using a `#heading` and/or `---` hrule to separate them.

Comment: Given that you are a @ConspicuousCompiler I expected you to have a -pedantic flag.

Comment: @PeterCordes I disagree. If they provide 2 answers - one that works, and one that doesn't, then doesn't it make more sense to vote on those two answers individually? If they are logically separate, there isn't any really a good reason I can think of to join them just because they're from the same author...

Comment: @Shadow: yes, good point.  It all depends on *how* separate they are.  But if it's the same algorithm implemented with SSE vs. AVX intrinsics for example, then it probably belongs in the same answer.  Or 2 variations on the same idea.  But I've posted multiple answers on [AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36932240) where AVX512 adds a new instruction specifically for this operation.

Comment: If I know multiple solution I usually (as an expert) able to choose the *best* one. If it doesn't work for OP, then I may edit the answer to add more options. Posting new answer is weird, but I also did it once. The right course of action in such case is to remove latter answer with its content edited into earlier one.

Comment: Yielding to the pedantry to make it stop. Kind of missing the point.

Comment: I admit I was guilty of leaving two answers.  The reason being is transparency of my thought process.  In the recent answers that i supplied where I left more than one answer was because either the original poster commented on the answer, or I thought that answer was cleaner than the accepted answer.  As I stated in a prior comment above, I will refrain from leaving multiple answers.  If I come up with a better answer, I will edit and eliminate the prior efforts that I put forth.

Comment: @jeffld just a friendly tip, it probably might help if we consider [Stack Exchange is partly based off Wiki](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/about/venn-diagram.png) where we mostly only care about the final, clean result. Also, your prior efforts aren't *really* lost since there is a revision history for every edit. But if you want to document your whole thought process, then probably a personal blog may be more suitable, instead of a strict Q&A site...

Comment: I've discovered that most problems require an iterative process to solve.  I have recently noticed the edit feature and the edit revisions which is available.  I believe that all have access to viewing the edit history to see the various iterations that happened in the process of answering the question.  [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development)

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler `can` is not the semantically the same as `always`( see also [`may`, `must`, `shall`](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) ) and is an important distinction

Comment: Bit off topic perhaps but that edit link in the lower left hand corner is not very obvious and is easy for new users to overlook.  Not even styled as a button.  There have been several occasions over the years where I have pointed out the link after a user tries to use comments or answers to modify their questions.  Might consider making it just a bit more prominent or obvious.

Answer (score 4):

I think that sometimes, a single question can have more than one answer.  There is e.g. more than one way to allocate memory for a program in C++.  A single user leaving more than one discrete (i.e. truly different) and viable (i.e. plausibly useful) answers allows the different strategies for handling a problem to be voted on to see what's more popular (which isn't always the best solution, either).

In this case, providing updates with answers aren't separate answers.  I think that does sound like bad behavior.  If you just flag the user, the problem isn't really solved.  You still have noise they left throughout SO.  I recommend trying to contact the user via their message inbox, and explain to them that you believe that this has been a repeated problem with them, and that their answer history needs to be gone through to fix this.  Then, give them e.g. 15 days to respond, and if they are willing, 30 more to go through their answers.  This 1) gives them a chance to consolidate their own answers into discrete answers, and 2) saves you the work, on the off-chance that they should do it.  If they don't do it, I'd say, feel free to go through their record.  It's not stalking, if you explain that they're being followed, why, and what they can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you did the right thing.

However, leaving a comment would also be extremely helpful as the person may be posting multiple answers because he/she is not aware of certain features (like editing).

Nevertheless, posting multiple answers isn't exactly harmful as long as the answers are completely different. However, in a case where one answer is simply an update of the previous one, a flag (and an explanatory comment) should be raised.